# PHP push data to different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that contains the data of locations, now I want to split this array into multiple arrays sorted by the postal code(postal code is an item in the location array)

I have:

```
array(
[0]=>array([name]=>"name1", [postalcode]=>"1111", [etc]=>"etc"),
[1]=>array([name]=>"name2", [postalcode]=>"2222", [etc]=>"etc")
);
```

And I want to push the first item to an array with the name 1111 and the other to 2222(and this for 10000+ locations in about 4000 postal code areas)

Comment: So you want that to become: array(
[1111]=>array([name]=>"name1", [etc]=>"etc"),
[2222]=>array([name]=>"name2", [etc]=>"etc")
); or something else...?

Comment: Can you give your expected output?

Comment: array( [1111]=>array([0]=>array([name]=>"name1", [etc]=>"etc"), [1]=>array(etc)), [2222]=>array([0]=>array([name]=>"name2", [etc]=>"etc"), [1]=>array(etc)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)?

Reference is used for performance on large iterations. [READ MORE](http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html).

```
$input = array(
    array('name' => "name1", 'postalcode' => "1111", 'etc' => "etc"),
    array('name' => "name2", 'postalcode' => "2222", 'etc' => "etc"),
);

$result = array();

foreach ($input as &$array) {
    $result[$array['postalcode']][] = $array;
}
```

Comment: The `$result[$array['postalcode']] = array()` line is unnecessary BTW.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not something you want to do on every request. Consider changing the data structure from wherever you are reading this information.

Second, as far as I can see you need to go through the array and build a new one:

```
$per_code = array();
for ($c=0; $c<count($codes); $c++)
    $per_code[$codes[$c]['postalcode']] = $codes[$c];
```

If you want to reduce the memory impact, consider using the same instance from the original array.

```
$per_code = array();
for ($c=0; $c<count($codes); $c++)
    $per_code[$codes[$c]['postalcode']] = &$codes[$c];
```

Answer (score 0):

Say,

```
    $location =array(
                    array('name'=>"name1", 'postalcode'=>"1111", 'etc'=>"etc"),
                    array('name'=>"name2", 'postalcode'=>"2222", 'etc'=>"etc")
            );
            $newAry = array();
            foreach($location  as $key=>$value)
            {
                $postcode = $value['postalcode'];
                $newAry['location'][$postcode][] = $value;
            }
print_r($newAry);
```

Comment: oh wait, it doesn't work. I now only have one of every postal code but i need to have all the ones items with the same postalcode in 1 multidimensional array

Comment: Please try with updated code ....